# Can a single java class can be used as two differnt extensions?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp, equinox

Can a single java class can be used as two different extensions? I have two different extension-points. I want to use a single service class which can be used both the extensions. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the same class name in multiple extensions. However Eclipse will create separate instances of the class for each extension.

You can use the `IExecutableExtensionFactory` in extension points to specify an extension factory which could be used to use a single instance of the class.

Comment: Hi @greg-449, thanks for your reply. You mean two different instances or two different references here?

Comment: Multiple instances of the class will be created using `Class.newInstance`. See `org.eclipse.core.runtime.spi.RegistryStrategy#createExecutableExtension`